# How can I add NuGet packages to one project in my solution and share those packages with all of my other projects in the solution?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget-package

I'm working in Visual Studio with a solution that has several projects. Many of these projects all use the same NuGet packages. Every time I need to update the packages I have to go manage the package for the entire solution then select the check box for every project and update them.

Is there no way for me to add the NuGet packages into a single class library project and then just reference that project from the other projects that need the packages? This seemed to work when I was dealing with .net standard class library projects but not with .net framework. When I do this, the Nuget package assemblies are not available.

My goal with this would be to only have to update the packages in one project which would basically take care of it for all of the other projects in the solution that are using those packages.